# WCF & Basic Authentication

Tags: wcf, basic-authentication

I want to configure basic authentication on my IIS7 that is hosting several WCF/ASMX services, moreover I want my clients to store user name and passwords inside the web.config file without modify client code, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure IIS7 for basic authentication, however this would authenticate against Local Users and Groups rather than the web.config configuration file.

I would not recommend putting them in the configuration file as then you would have to go to the effort of encrypting the passwords and you would also have to modify your code to use a custom authentication method.

Comment: Agreed. Consider using the Sample ASP.Net Sql CE Membership Provider.